# How to Implement decorator which returns function signature and it's return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

How to Implement decorator which returns function signature and it's return value?

def some(func):
"""
:param func: function
"""
# YOUR CODE HERE

@some
def add(a, b):
return a + b

add(4, 5)

It should return this: # add(4, 5) was called and returned 9'.
Have no clue how to realize that. Could someone help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Creating decorators can be tricky for people new to programming or python. A general pattern for decorators is:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do stuff
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
     return wrapper
```

While it may seem complicated at first, basically the decorator takes the function you create as input (`add` in this case). It then wraps your `add` function with the `wrapper` function. This allows you to inject whatever logic you like before or after the `add` function is called.

I've included some code below to solve your specific problem.

```
def print_each_call(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        output = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'function {func.__name__}{args} was called and output {output}')
        return output

    return wrapper


@print_each_call
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(1, 2))
# output (first line is from the decorator. Second line is from print()):
# function add(1, 2) was called and output 3
# 3
```